# python GUI: how to create a "table" to incude both chart (by matplotlib) and text (pandas data)?

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas

I have several groups of data and I want to have a table to both visualize them and summarize some important features. What I want is something like the following:

[image]

The data are known and it is easy to get these features. But how to have a table (**or whatever widget, as long as it shows like a table**) to include both the small chart like a thumbnail (plotted by matplotlib)?
Is there a way I can use any Python GUI library (e.g., tkinter) to make it? I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

- This image is created in Excel :(
- We should be able to control the size of the chart so that it can "fit" the font of the text (data).
- The borderlines are preferred but not required.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you could use pyside/pyqt for. In pyqt all text labels can also be set as images, so you can just save your images from matplotlib and load them in PYQT. PYQT has an editor that generates your front end code, so I would recommend just downloading it and playing a bit with the editor. But PYQT is only good if you want a live GUI.

If you want to generate a file, just use excel like you are already doing with openpyxl (https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)? I use it for a lot of my reports. With PIL you can add images from matplotlib.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will have a look at PYQT (I've never tried it before). The data will be real-time and the chart may change from time to time. At a time, I may add one group of data or delete a group of data from the "table". Hence, I cannot save the matplotlib plots, as they will get updated from time to time. It is just like stocks. It is easy to include only images or texts, but it is difficult for me to include both in each row.